# Error during template rendering : NoReverseMatch at /products/product-3/

Tags: python, django, django-views

Can you please help me understand the below error?
I am learning Django, and really stuck with the reverse rendering of the views.
When I click on the product link it should go to product page but throws the error.

**My analysis**
I inserted print statements in product single function and could see in terminal that program works okay until it goes to render the view, does this help ?

**from the terminal**

```
15/Nov/2020 22:49:59] "GET /products/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7582
<WSGIRequest: GET '/products/product-3/'>
{'product': <Product: Product 3>, 'images': <QuerySet []>}
products/single.html
Internal Server Error: /products/product-3/
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

**Error**
NoReverseMatch at /products/product-3/
Reverse for 'add_to_cart' not found. 'add_to_cart' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/product-3/
Django Version: 3.1.3
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:
Reverse for 'add_to_cart' not found. 'add_to_cart' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

**HTML**

```
{% extends "base.html" %} {% block content %}
<h1>Search for {{ query }}</h1>
{{ product }}

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <th></th>
    <th>Product</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for product in product_htm %}
    <tr>
      <td>Image</td>
      <td><a href="{ product.get_absolute_url }}"> {{ product }}</a></td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
{% endblock %}
```

**models.py in product app**

```
# Create your models here.
class Product(models.Model):
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("product_app:single_product", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})
```

**products views.py**

```
def single(request, slug):
    product = Product.objects.get(slug=slug)
    images = ProductImage.objects.filter(product=product)
    context = {'product': product, 'images': images}
    template = 'products/single.html'
    print(request)
    print(context)
    print(template)
    return render(request, template, context)
```

**product app urls.py**
from . import views

```
app_name = 'product_app'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='home'),
    path('s/', views.search),
    path('products/', views.all, name='products'),
    path('products/<slug:slug>/', views.single, name='single_product'),
]
```

**carts urls.py**

```
from . import views
# import (index, ProductSingleView)

app_name = 'cart_app'

extra_patterns = [
    path('cart/carts/<slug:slug>/', views.add_to_cart),
]
urlpatterns = [
    path('cart/', include(extra_patterns), name='add_to_cart'),
    path('cart/<int:id>', views.remove_from_cart, name='remove_from_cart'),
    path('', views.view, name='cart'),
]
```

**carts views.py**

```
# Create your views here.
from products.models import Product, Variation
from .models import Cart, CartItem


def view(request):
    try:
        the_id = request.session['cart_id']
    except DoesNotExist:
        the_id = None
    if the_id:
        cart = Cart.objects.get(id=the_id)
        new_total = 0.00
        for item in cart.cartitem_set.all():
            line_total = float(item.product.price) * item.quantity
            new_total += line_total

        request.session['items_total'] = cart.cartitem_set.count()
        cart.total = new_total
        cart.save()
        
        context = {"cart": cart}
    else:
        empty_message = "Yout cart is empty, please keep shopping"
        context = {"empty": True, "empty_message": empty_message}

    template = "cart/view.html"
    return render(request, template, context)

def remove_from_cart(request, id):
    try:
        the_id = request.session['cart_id']
        cart = Cart.objects.get(id=the_id)
    except:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('cart_app:cart'))

    cartitem = CartItem.objects.get(id=id)
    cartitem.cart = None
    cartitem.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('cart_app:cart'))

def add_to_cart(request, slug):
    request.session.set_expiry(120)

    try:
        the_id = request.session['cart_id']
    except:
        new_cart = Cart()
        new_cart.save()
        request.session['cart_id'] = new_cart.id
        the_id = new_cart.id

    cart = Cart.objects.filter(id=the_id)

    try:
        product = Product.objects.get(slug=slug)
    except Product.DoesNotExist:
        print("except1")

    product_var = []
    if request.method == "POST":
        qty = request.POST['qty']
        for item in request.POST:
            key = item
            val = request.POST[key]
            try:
                v = Variation.objects.get(product=product, category__iexact=key, title__iexact=val)
                product_var.append(v)
            except Variation.DoesNotExist:
                pass

        cart_item = CartItem.objects.create(cart=cart, product=product)
        print("iam here")
        if len(product_var) > 0:
            # * adds each item
            cart_item.variations.add(*product_var)
        cart_item.quantity = qty
        cart_item.save()


        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('cart_app:cart'))
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('cart_app:cart'))
```

**urls.py in project ecommerce**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('products.urls')),
    path('cart/', include('carts.urls'), name='cart'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: you probably have reverse to non existing reverse name in template

Comment: I just added more information to the question, hopefully this gives out some specifics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your url_patterns, the line with `name='add_to_cart'` is on the include. Take that name out and put it on the line in the extra_patterns. I think you are trying to name the include which could have several items.

```
from . import views
# import (index, ProductSingleView)

app_name = 'cart_app'

extra_patterns = [
    path('cart/carts/<slug:slug>/', views.add_to_cart, name='add_to_cart'),
]
urlpatterns = [
    path('cart/', include(extra_patterns)),
    path('cart/<int:id>', views.remove_from_cart, name='remove_from_cart'),
    path('', views.view, name='cart'),
]
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks a million, you saved me. thanks for helping me out

Answer (score 0):

First thing I can see is that there is a typo in your html file. You have only one left curly bracket for

> product.get_absolute_url

Also, when you call `get_absolute_url` it returns

> reverse("product_app:single_product", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

Make sure that the product indeed has `self.slug` because I can't tell if the product class in your models.py has any fields.

Please let me know if that helps, I would love to try to help.

Comment: Thanks - yes this is a mistake which I corrected now. thanks for helping me out